# python class inheritance definition

Tags: python

Lets take the next code

```
class main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 4
        self.methods = sub

class sub:
    def printval():
        print(a,b)
```

How can I use main class in this way?

```
main.methods.printval()
```

Comment: You want `self.methods = sub()`. Then you can do `self.methods.printval()`.

Comment: This is not inheritance. This isn't even a [new-style class](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass). `sub` has no way to access your attributes 'a', and 'b'.

Comment: However, based on how you are looking to print `a` and `b` which seems to indicate the `a` and `b` attributes from `main`, you seem to not be structuring things the way you should. You should probably try to re-think your strategy here. Or maybe, you can share what it is you are trying to achieve exactly? This could be an XY problem.

Comment: I was trying with `self.methods.printval ()` but I am not a real expert in python classes, can you show me with a little example? It would be helpful for me

Comment: @ZaulAE Look at the answer someone provided. It gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: Sure, I am trying to make a main class with some attributes, and create methods in different groups, such as main.statistics, main.plots, main.methods, but that they can use the attributes of main class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a bizzare thing to do, but here goes

```
class Main(object):
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'methods')
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 4
        self.methods = Sub(self)

class Sub:
    __slots__ = ('other')
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.other = other;

    def printval(self):
        print(self.other.a, self.other.b)
```

---

```
main = Main()
main.methods.printval()
```

Also there is no inheritance going on between `Main` and `Sub`. You are simply taking advantage of function calls.

### EDIT:

Another way of accomplishing the same thing, but this time using inheritance:

```
class Main(object):
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 4

class Sub(Main):
    def printval(self):
        print(self.a, self.b)
```

---

```
main = Sub()
main.printval()
```

Comment: I was thinking that It could be a normal declaration in python, but as you say It looks bizarre, but thanks It is really helpful for me.

Comment: @ZaulAE If you want to use a more "normal" Python construct, you could simply inheirt from `Main` in `Sub`, and use the call `Sub().printval()` instead. Unless this contrived example, I really don't see why you need or want what your asking for.

Comment: @ZaulAE. You could add more details of what it is you are trying to accomplish, then maybe we can be of better help. If this is actually what you were after, then by all means please find a different way. This kind of code is the stuff of nightmares if it makes it into real-world use

Comment: @smac89, Thanks for stopped me in my crazy intent of code. In summary, I want to create a class with some attributes, and I want to join similar methods in "categories" that use this attributes, for example, create a main.statistics to store all statistics methods that I need. I was thinking that It could be a good idea for classify the methods, but I can use it in a  simply way like main.statistics_mean, main.statistics_std ... and avoid a complex structure